# Can Younggen throw outofmemory error?

Tags: java, jvm

```
XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=15
```

in JRE7. What if by the time there isnt any room left in eden+s1+s2 spaces? Would younggen throw outofmemory?
I havent seen this happening but got curious if someone has experienced it.

Answer (score 1):

This might depend on the implementation but usually no as it is not a set value, just an upper limit. In case there's no more room in eden and/or survivor spaces the object is directly copied to the old gen, when there's no room there then the JVM first tries to perform collection. Even when you set `XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=0` it will just mean that the objects will get promoted immediately.

Take into account that this parameter sets the upper limit, the actual value is decided [by the JVM](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html)

> Maximum value for tenuring threshold. The default value is 15.

As the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html) states:

> Thrown when the Java Virtual Machine cannot allocate an object because it is out of memory, and no more memory could be made available by the garbage collector.

The problem will start when the number of swaps between s1 and s2 surpasses that value and there is no free memory in old gen (and the GC cannot free any).

Take into account that setting that value to too low might be a problem if your objects are short lived but get promoted to old gen too fast. On the other hand if most of your objects is long lived then making them swap between s1 and s2 is also not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for your response and detailed clarification. I was under similar understanding however, havent seen that in action, so asked. It wouldnt make sense if eden would go out of space when tenured space, usually 3x larger, is available to java heap. I think "Take into account that this parameter sets the upper limit, the actual value is decided by the JVM" clarifies it further. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

> What if by the time there isnt any room left in eden+s1+s2 spaces?

This trigger a full GC.  This causes all the objects to be copied to the tenured space. The tenured space can normally be resized but if your prevent this and the tenured space fills up, you get an OutOfMemoryError.